# Moving multiple UIImageView with UIAccelerometer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can anyone post or direct to how move multiple `UIImageView` objects depending on the `Accelerometer` movement.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple guys provide this illustration of how to "smooth" the raw data coming from the accelerometer in the docs:

```
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:
  (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
  // Use a basic low-pass filter to keep only the gravity component of each axis.
  accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
  accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
  accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
}
```

Once you have the data stream, simply alter the deltax,deltay you have for a set of images, within some minimum/maximum ranges, and reposition each UIImageView, eg:

```
// in your @interface somewhere
float deltax, deltay;
UIView* ivs[9];

// in your @implementation
#define MINXDELTA (-40)
#define MAXXDELTA (+40)
#define MINYDELTA (-40)
#define MAXYDELTA (+40)
#define SPEEDFACTOR (5)
#define kFilteringFactor 0.1
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:
  (UIAcceleration *)acceleration {
  // Use a basic low-pass filter to keep only the gravity component of each axis.
  accelX = (acceleration.x * kFilteringFactor) + (accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
  accelY = (acceleration.y * kFilteringFactor) + (accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
  accelZ = (acceleration.z * kFilteringFactor) + (accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor));
  deltax+=accelX*SPEEDFACTOR; deltay+=accelY*SPEEDFACTOR;
  if (deltax<MINXDELTA) deltax=MINXDELTA;
  if (deltay<MINYDELTA) deltay=MINYDELTA;
  if (deltax>MINXDELTA) deltax=MINXDELTA;
  if (deltay>MINYDELTA) deltay=MINYDELTA;
  [self positionImages];
}
// call this from init too
-(void)positionImages {
  // assumes you have 9 images arranged as 3x3 on 40 pixel grid centered at 100,100
  for (ix=0; ix<3; ix++) for (iy=0; iy<3; iy++) {
    UIImageView *iv=ivs[ix+iy*3];
    CGPoint c=CGMakePoint(100-40+40*ix, 100-40+40*iy);
    iv.center=c;
  }
}
```

EDIT

Some minor typos above.

```
UIView* ivs[9];
```

should be

```
UIImageView* ivs[9];
```

and

```
  if (deltax>MINXDELTA) deltax=MINXDELTA;
  if (deltay>MINYDELTA) deltay=MINYDELTA;
```

should be

```
  if (deltax>MAXXDELTA) deltax=MAXXDELTA;
  if (deltay>MAXYDELTA) deltay=MAXYDELTA;
```

That's enough of a pointer / I'll leave it there I think.

Comment: thanks for the respond! can you explain a bit more? how to define the images here, what to call in viewdidload?

Comment: ()
* For this simple example, Images and image views created using [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile], [UIImageView initWithFrame:CGMakeRect(0,0,0,0)], [UIImageView setImage:] and [someParentView addSubView:] in [UIApplicationDelegate init]
* Calls to the acclerometer API to tell it to start and stop callling the didAccelerate method is required too
* If you are instead using view controllers you can call [appDelegate positionImages] from your [viewController viewDidLoad] method

Comment: i'm having problem with the positionImages method:

1. how to declare the ix and iy ?

2. i get invalid initializer on this - UIImageView *iv=ivs[ix+iy*3];

3. i want to use an uiimageview's that located already on the view using the ib (for separates location's, i don'y know how to do that on code...). 

thanks!

btw [appDelegate positionImages] you meant [self positionImages]?